# How can I rewrite the Java's for loop to the swift5's for in loop in the following code?

Tags: java, swift5

For example, I would like to print a Triangle by using Swift5, but I just want to rewrite the code from java. I would like to see how "for in" loop work in swift 5.

For example, the java code is below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){

    for(int j = 5; i < j; j--){

     System.out.print(" ");

  }

    for(int k = 0; k <= i; k++){

     System.out.print("*");

  }

    for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++){

     System.out.print("*");

  }

     System.out.println();
}
```

I know there is other way to print a triangle, but I just want to know how I can rewrite this java code directly to a swift5 code. Especially how I can rewrite the inner loop judge condition like (k <= i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
for i in 0..<5{
    // 5,4,3,2,1 - " "
    for _ in stride(from: 5, to: i, by: -1){
        print(" ", terminator:"")
    }
    // 1,2,3,4,5 - "*"
    for _ in stride(from: 0, through: i, by: 1){
        print("*", terminator:"")
    }
    // 0,1,2,3,4 - "*"
    for _ in stride(from: 1, through: i, by: 1){
        print("*", terminator:"")
    }
    print(" ")
}
```